# PHP ZipArchive::open won't create a zip file

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I can't make ZipArchive create a zip file, but it won't give me any errors except for returning False on $zip->close();

I'm trying to create a zip archive in a directory a couple down from the one in which the operations are taking place.

```
$file_name = 'example.txt';  // or whatever, I'm including a few

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$path = getcwd() . '/output/run1/';
$zip_name = 'files_run1.zip';
$zip_p_name = $path . $zip_name;

$res = $zip->open($zip_p_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if (!($res ===TRUE))     echo 'failed, code:'.$res;
else
  {
    if (file_exists($zip_path . '/' . $file_name))
      {
        $add = $zip->addFile($zip_path . '/' . $file_name);
        if (!($add)) echo "didn't work";
      }
    else echo "File doesn't exist!";

    $close = $zip->close();
    if ($close)    echo 'File Closed';
    else           echo 'fail!!';
  }
```

That little lot only outputs 'fail!!'. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: you have a stray asterisk on `$zip_p_name`

Comment: Do you have permissions to create a file in that path. Try using fopen, instead of ZipArchive just to check

Comment: The stray asterisk is a typo I made while I was copying the code, it's not really there. But well spotted. I'll try with the permissions in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome bumperbox, that solved it. I had to chmod the permissions for the output/run1 file to give write access to group, and I had to ensure Apache was in group. This seems ill advised for security reasons, but I have the whole site password protected so should be ok. If you want to write it as an answer I'll select it as correct if you like.